# How can I incorporate text in my model?

Tags: 3d-models, blender

I feel this is a relatively simple thing, but I am having some difficulty. The model is simple. It is 2 x 127 x 28 x π mm. It has one corrugated side and all others flat. The non-flat side has a flat area for text.

(Later deformed into a cylinder, hence pi (π))

The problem I'm having in Blender is a *lot* of non-manifold vertices after the union of the text into that area.

Is it possible to have the text and widget as two different meshes touching and come out as one object *in the print*?

Use another program besides Blender?

Manually editing the mesh... seems excessively time consuming.

Comment: This does not look to be 3D printing related, but rather a question about Blender that would be better suited for [Blender.SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @agarza Potentially. But am curious about any method to solve the problem. I'm not tied to Blender. If someone uses another application and has no issues... I'm eager to hear what the application is.

Comment: Unless your question can be [edit]ed to be [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it is at risk of being closed.

Comment: This question appears to ask for modeling software alternatives to blender. If modeling software falls under the realm of this SE, the question appears valid.

Comment: @fred_dot_u 3D models and programs are only on topic insofar they show that it is a question for 3D printing and not other uses. See https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/501/cad-questions-review - The bar is super low: just declare that the model is to be printable.

Comment: @Trish - "super low bar", this made me smile... you're right, the bar is ridiculously low, when you come to think about it. We seem to be easy to please... :-)

Comment: Interesting things I've stirred up. :) Sadly I have a bad habit with stack exchanges... I'm stuck, sometimes for days. Can't figure it out. Ask. Figure it out.

Comment: Hi Nolan. I'm trying to do some site housekeeping. As your question has generated an accepted (and upvoted) answer, could you do the site a favour and just [edit] your question to confirm that you intend to print the model (once you've found the appropriate software)? If you do that, then all of the above comments can be deleted. Thanks :-) Your question has some close votes against it because the question may not be 3DP related, so by editing and stating that the model *will* be printed would also remove those close votes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of options with respect to adding text to a shape. Top of the list would be the easy-to-use Tinkercad, but it may be too limiting for your purposes.

More complex, and coming in next would be the free hobbyist version of Fusion 360. In very many ways, a tougher program to learn, but YouTube tutorials may get you started on your specific objective.

My favorite would be to learn the wonders of OpenSCAD, a text based descriptor program that uses parametric modeling to create 3D objects.

It's not impossible to create non-manifold with the above three programs, but very much easier to create a working model.

If your final objective is a cylinder, it might be good to start with the desired shape and apply the text in the program of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @fred_dot_u! I did figure something out as well... probably something that these programs might do under the hood. I have a "bad habit," perhaps of my noob-ness, where I boolean union meshes to create one mesh for one object. There is another option to create one object... take the text mesh, abutt it to your object with snap, Ctrl+J... join. Avoids the boolean union, keeps the meshes as is, no non-manifold vertices/edges are formed, all joined are considered one object. I accepted yours as it provides people with options.

Comment: @NolanRobidoux - your comment looks like it should actually be an answer as it is a solution to the issue in your question.